# RESTful API for authroization, plan features control

Tags: restful-architecture

I am working on a web app. Front-end only interacts with back-end through RESTful API(it's called SOA architecture), and back-end only sends data to front-end in JSON.

My question is:
1) is it the best practice to design the authorization through RESTful API? or it is best to check authorization (user-> role -> privilege) at back-end code? 
e.g.: do we ask user /checkPrivilege/{...} every time before executing other API?

2) How it is usually to implement 3 plans with different features & UI in RESTful API? 
   e.g.: do we use api to limits 5 users for this plan? or we do it at back-end code?

Comment: The URL `/checkPrivilege/{...}` suggests that your API might not be as RESTful as you think. Remember: Your URLs should not look like method calls. A URL is supposed to identify a resource.

Comment: You are right. How do I design the authorization service? shall I do it in RESTful API? or at back-end?

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question, but I'll answer this anyway just in case some looks it up.

The short answer is you do it through the backend. The URI you are requesting should not contain any information about the user. Any session/identifying data should be sent in HTTP Headers.

Your RESTful API is always going to be loaded through a front controller like index.php. This is where you will want to bootstrap an authorization tool to check every single page request for credentials before executing the rest of your code.

Those credentials, at a MINIMUM, should contain a unique authorization token for the user who is making the request, and this token needs to be sent in every request (again, I recommend via an HTTP header). Bonus points if you grant a temporary access token that will expire, so as to prevent unauthorized access at a later date.

But for simplicity, let's say you are just using a permanent unique token per user. You would then store this token along with all the other data about the user, that other data should include an account_id for the account that user is a part of.

So for each request you would:

1. grab the user token from the HTTP Header
2. Look up the user based on that token.
3. If the user is found, then use their account_id to look up the master account their personal account is associated with
4. If it matches, grant them access

But remember, your URL should never contain this information in anyway. RESTful URLs are stateless.